# Rspec not recognizing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm running a simple test to list an objects attributes.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'List Movies' do 
    it 'Lists all movies' do 

        movie1 = Movie.create(

            title: "Iron Man",
            rating: "PG-13",
            total_gross: 10000000

            )

        movie2 = Movie.create(

            title: "Super Man",
            rating: "PG",
            total_gross: 120000000

            )

        movie3 = Movie.create(

            title: "Spider Man",
            rating: "R-16",
            total_gross: 30000000

            )

        visit movies_url

        expect(page).to have_text("3 Movies")

        expect(page).to have_text(movie1.title)
        expect(page).to have_text(movie2.title)
        expect(page).to have_text(movie3.title)

        expect(page).to have_text(movie1.title)
        expect(page).to have_text(movie1.rating)
        expect(page).to have_text("10000000")


    end
end
```

It comes back to me with uninitialized constant Movie.

so i run a generator.

```
rails g model Movie title:string rating:string total_gross:decimal --no-test-framework.
```

I run the test again, `rspec spec/features/list_movies_spec.rb.`

Yet, still the same error, i've done this a hundred times before, why is it not recognizing the model after running the generator?.

Comment: Is this a new app using Rspec 3.0? If so, you should be requiring 'rails_helper' instead of 'spec_helper'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Rspec 3.0, running `rails g rspec:install` creates a `rails_helper.rb` file now to be used instead of `spec_helper.rb`, so you should be requiring that instead at the top of your specs:

```
require 'rails_helper'
```

You'll see that the Rspec generator actually still created a `spec_helper` file, but that file does nothing; it's mostly commented out. `rails_helper` is where the Rails environment (which includes your models) is loaded.

The reasoning for this is that you may have specs that don't need to load the entire Rails stack, so those specs can continue to use the `spec_helper` file. There is an [upgrade guide for moving from rspec-rails 2.x to 3.x](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade)

Comment: Hey Dylan, do you know how to get rid of that massive stack dump that runs on the test?